# How do I refer to a table that will be copied?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a model that is formatted as a table so I can run calculations through the rows within it. There's several subs that that do different calculations, and those work fine. The different calculations use the headers to index which column they're supposed to use for the calculation, but as the table is copied the name will change by adding numbers to the end.

Usually, I create a copy and use the copy for the historical data then use original table to update information and re-run the model.

Is there a way to adjust my code so it uses the table on the `ActiveSheet`? There won't be any cases where there is more than 1 table on any given tab.

Currently I use something like below to reference the columns in the other subs I have created, but I use this sub as a one-stop shop to have everything defined so if I need to add and define I can maintain it in one place. You can ignore the references to ranges, as those seem to work fine since they're sheet specific names.

```
Private Sub DefineVars()
'Defines my already declared variables

Calc = ActiveSheet.Range("_Calc")
dmCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_Table_Pricer").ListColumns("$ Margin").Index
fxmCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_Table_Pricer").ListColumns("FX Margin").Index
mCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_Table_Pricer").ListColumns("% Margin").Index
cCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_Table_Pricer").ListColumns("% Margin ").Index
spCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_Table_Pricer").ListColumns("Sell Price").Index
Set UoM = ActiveSheet.Range("_Unit_Factor")
Set FxRate = ActiveSheet.Range("_FX_Rate")
Goal = ActiveSheet.Range("_Mah_Min")
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` will always refer to the table if there is only one table on the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting the comment into an answer.  If there will never be more than 1 table on a sheet then `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` will do what you want.

If there can be more than table then it is safer to evaluate the table name or contents to find the table you want.

Comment: I feel like I should take you name because I feel Profoundly Oblivious for not realizing this, and you seemed to point out the profoundly obvious. Enjoy the extra rep ;)

Comment: @Mark S  Thank you sir, may I have another!

Comment: I'm about to post another somewhat related question regarding a specific calculation that faces a similar challenge and you're more than welcome to assist with that

Comment: In case you're interested: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677877/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-table-copies)