# How do I set a variable to table copies?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that will be copied as new tabs are created. There are different subs that do different calculations depending on what the scenario dictates. One scenario, we need to calculate a difference between two entities' margin and use a goal seek to make that difference zero. I achieve this by creating a column that calculates that then deleting it, but if there is a better way of achieving this I'm open to that if it avoids this overall problem (I'll adjust the question if needed)

However since the table is copied I'm unsure how to add a formula to the new column without naming the table as you would if you were writing the formula in the cell itself. What I have below works, but only on the original table.

```
Sub PercentMarginSplit()
'This adds a column to calc the dif, between margins
'It uses this column to zero out the margin dif
'Creating a % margin split
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
Call DefineVars
Call TurnOffFunctions

Dim pCol As Integer
Dim Splitter As Range

Set pSplit = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Add
pSplit.Name = "Percent Split"
Set Splitter = Range("_Table_Pricer[Percent Split]")
Splitter.Formula = "=_Table_Pricer[@[% Margin ]] - _Table_Pricer[@[% Margin]]"
pCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").Index

For row_no = 5 To LastRow
    If Calc = "Check" Then
        If Cells(row_no, mCol) < Goal Then
            Cells(row_no, pCol).GoalSeek _
            Goal:=0, _
            Changingcell:=Cells(row_no, cCol)
        End If
    Else:
        Cells(row_no, pCol).GoalSeek _
        Goal:=0, _
        Changingcell:=Cells(row_no, cCol)
    End If
Next

ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").Delete
Call TurnOnFunctions

End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for explicitly qualifying `ListObject` calls off the `ActiveSheet`! FYI `Cells` and `Range` are *implicitly* referring to `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: The unqualified `Range` in `Range("_Table_Pricer[Percent Split]")` works on whatever the current active sheet is. If you do `Worksheets("SheetImInterestedIn").Range(...)`, then you'll know for sure you're working on that sheet.

Comment: @FreeMan the idea is that this would work on any tab and on any copy of the table (only 1 table per tab), so I'm avoiding naming the worksheet, otherwise the code will only work for the table in that sheet.

Comment: Don't need table name if you know what columns you're working with; just like you don't need a table name if you know what table you're working with - it's the same principle of using an index number instead of a name.  I would look into `ActiveSheet.Colums(#)` for a column outside the table, `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(#)` for a column inside the table, or work with individual cells using `Offset`... Or maybe I don't understand the objective.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious Where the columns are can change as we add different data points to the table, so I stay away from numbering columns or offsetting since this can change. But I found a solution where I can keep my names AND work with copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're very close to having this right.

As Mathieu Guindon mentioned, you're explicitly referencing the **`ListObject`** (i.e. table) on the `ActiveSheet` to add a column to it.

```
Set pSplit = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Add
pSplit.Name = "Percent Split"
```

However, on the next lines, you're accessing the table on the `ActiveSheet` by its name.

```
Set Splitter = Range("_Table_Pricer[Percent Split]")
```

1. The unqualified `Range` call will work on the `ActiveSheet` by design. I understand you're trying to use this to your advantage to have it run on whatever sheet is active when the user hits the key combo. *However*, I'd caution that this can, and likely will, come back to bite you at some point when you least expect it.  I'd suggest something like this:

```
Dim curWorksheet As Worksheet
Set curWorksheet = ActiveSheet
Set Splitter = curWorksheet.Range("_Table_Pricer[Percent Split]")
```

This will ensure that no matter what else happens during the execution of this code (either by code or by a bored user clicking on another worksheet) you're always going to be processing against what *was* the `ActiveSheet` *when the routine started* which is, I believe, your intent.

2. You're setting your `Range` to a named range `"_Table_Pricer[]"`. That named table exists *only* on the original worksheet where you explicitly named it. When you copy the worksheet, either by hand or by code, the new worksheet will have a new copy of the table and the table will be named `Tablex` where `x` is some incremental number based on however many tables have been declared in this workbook since the beginning of time.

Since you now have defined `curWorksheet` to be whatever `ActiveSheet` was (and may still be) pointing at, use it like this

```
Set Splitter = curWorksheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split")
```

<sub>NOTE: air coding here, it may need a minor tweak or two to ensure you're getting the whole range</sub>

This will set `Splitter` to be the range of whatever the `ListObject(1)` is on the worksheet, no matter what `Tablex` name Excel has given it.

Comment: Great answer, I think the explanation and caution will help the OP if taken to heart.

Comment: @FreeMan the `Set Splitter` you gave caused a type mismatch, I figured out it was because it was originally declared as a range whereas this is calling to it as an object. So my solution to this was instead to amend that like so `Set Splitter = ws.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").DataBodyRange` which got everything working.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MarkS.! Did I mention that it was `Air Code™` and that some adjustment might be necessary? :D

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just explaining the error it produced, where it happened and what needed to be added (`.databodyrange`) to fix it

Comment: I threw you the answer points, since you got me most of the way there, and there's no benefit to checking my own answer.

Comment: Awww, what a swell guy you are @MarkS.! More unicorns and leprechaun gold for me!! :) Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked with the help of @Freeman & @ProfoundlyOblivious is below. I added a `ws = Activesheet` into the reference for the range `Splitter` (named variables had them already there).

This allows me **create copies of my table, add columns, put a formula in those columns and run my calculation looping through the rows with a goal seek and then delete the column** created on the copied table!

```
Sub PercentMarginSplit()
'This adds a column to calc the dif between margins
'It uses this column to zero out the margin dif
'Creating a % margin split
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
Call DefineVars
Call TurnOffFunctions

Dim pCol As Integer
Dim Splitter As Range

Set pSplit = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Add
pSplit.Name = "Percent Split"
Set Splitter = ws.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").DataBodyRange
Splitter.Formula = "=[@[% Margin ]] - [@[% Margin]]"
pCol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").Index

For row_no = 5 To LastRow
    If Calc = "Check" Then
        If Cells(row_no, mCol) < Goal Then
            Cells(row_no, pCol).GoalSeek _
            Goal:=0, _
            Changingcell:=Cells(row_no, cCol)
        End If
    Else:
        Cells(row_no, pCol).GoalSeek _
        Goal:=0, _
        Changingcell:=Cells(row_no, cCol)
    End If
Next

ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Percent Split").Delete
Call TurnOnFunctions

End Sub
```